# No protocol error, java, when uploading file

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, url, jar

I'm running a jar file but I get the following errors when I want to upload a file (which exists).

```
ufuoma@ufuoma-VirtualBox:~/ltserver$ java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l en "file:Here.doc"
ERROR [Thread-1]: Error getting url: no protocol: Here.doc (AppInterface.java:140)
```

The part of the AppInterface.java file where the error is generated is (I commented line 140 for easy tracking):

```
public void run() {
        byte[] anaContent;
        byte[] ontContent;
        byte[] dceContent;
        Document doc = null;

        try {
        //create new Document object, initial status == FAILED
            DocumentStatus status = new DocumentStatus(DocumentStatus.Status.PROCESSING, "Preprocessing");
            doc = new Document(id, LangCode.toInt(lang), status, true, 0);
            doc.lockRW();

            //add the document and process it
            docControl.addDocument(doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = "Error adding document: "+e.getMessage();
    /*Line 140*/ log.error(error);
            try {
                if (doc != null) {
                    docControl.setDocumentStatus(doc, DocumentStatus.Status.FAILED, error);
                    doc.unlockRW();
                }
                db.sync();    //FIXME
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // ignore
            }
            return;
        }

        try {
            // save the document data
            log.debug("reading URL...");
            docControl.setDocumentStatus(doc, DocumentStatus.Status.PROCESSING, "Reading source document");
            readURL(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = "Error getting url: "+e.getMessage();
            log.error(error);
            try {
                docControl.setDocumentStatus(doc, DocumentStatus.Status.FAILED, error);
                doc.unlockRW();
                db.sync();    //FIXME
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // ignore
            }
            return;
```

The options for the `send` command are:

```
- send a LO (test.xml) into the LTserver, language is set to Czech. test.xml must reside in the Docs directory as specified in the property file.

    $ java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l cs "test LO.xml"

By default, ID is a file name ("test LO.xml" in our example). To assign different ID, you can prepend it to the file name (separated by a colon). E.g. to give the learning object ID "lo1":

    $ java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l cs "lo1:test LO.xml"
```

I've tried the following:

```
java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l en "file:Here.doc"
java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l en "Here.doc"
java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l en "file:/path/to/Here.doc"
java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l en "/path/to/Here.doc"
```

But it still gives the same error. I don't know where the problem is. Thanks

Comment: Actually, the options for the comand are: `send a LO (test LO.xml) into the LTserver, language is set to Czech. test.xml must reside in the Docs directory as specified in the property file.
 $ java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l cs "test LO.xml"
By default, ID is a file name ("test LO.xml" in our example). To assign different ID, you can prepend it to the file name (separated by a colon). E.g. to give the learning object ID "lo1":
 $ java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l cs "lo1:test LO.xml"` So `file:` is just to give it a name. I don't know if that helps

Comment: Sort of : I now know you're not trying to pass the file through an URL using the file scheme, so my previous comment is useless. No idea why you're getting that `Error getting url: no protocol: Here.doc` though ; it seems like you shouldn't bother about urls and the application should handle them on its own. From what I get you should however be passing two things in your argument ; in their example `test LO.xml` corresponds to two files, a `test.xml` that must reside in the Docs directory and an `LO.xml` which  assume is to be found in the current directory.

Comment: I was thinking that was just a typographical error and the name of the file is actually `test LO.xml`

Comment: Yeah you're most probably right, they mention a `test LO.xml` file further in the description. I'm not sure I can help you further without any knowledge of that application. You could try contacting the application maintainer (for instance through their website's [contact page](http://www.lt4el.eu/index.php?content=contact))

Comment: Well, thanks for the effort @Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifications actually required a HTTP url and I was giving it a file from my local system as `file:///` which it couldn't resolve as FTP. Hence, I was getting: `ERROR [Thread-1]: Error getting url: no protocol: . . .`. To workaround it, I put the file on the XAMPP server - `path/to/opt/lampp/htdocs/file` - and could assess it through: `http://localhost:file` which was a valid HTTP url.